# Project Tool without an exisiting Geographic transformation using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, coordinates, arcgis-engine

I'm trying to insert a layer and in my project and while several other layers have been projected correctly on-the-fly by ArcGIS Pro, the final polygon layer is creating trouble. It slightly misfits to the other layers (approx. 50m away from the proper place, in a 1:5.000.000 scale). I'm aware that this is linked to a projection problem, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

What I tried so far:

1. Use the `Project Tool` with the CRS of the base maps and others
2. Use the `Define Projection Tool` with the CRS of the base maps and others
3. Use 1) and 2) consequently
4. Trying to create a `Geographic Transformation`-Oneliner manually, because the drop-down bar never appeared. Maybe the CRS is too exotic or wrongly named?
5. Creating a placeholder Featureclass with `Unknown CRS` to first project the `Unknown CRS` on the problematic layer and then redo 1)
6. Export Features from the problematic  layer and using the in-tool projection

[image: The original spatial information of the baselayer --> Desired one]

[image: The original spatial information of the problematic layer]

Comment: When you Define the projection, it may not be the same one as your Basemap or other layers. I would confirm with the data provider. Once the projection is correctly defined, ArcGIS Pro should be able to project on the fly it should line up with everything else. Or you can project it to the CRS of your other layers/basemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS doesn't recognize the geographic coordinate reference system (geoCRS), GCS_BESSEL_AUT so it can't find an existing transformation. I see the projected CRS is a modification of 31286, MGI / Austria M34. Try redefining just the geoCRS to 4312, MGI AKA Militar-Geographische Institut.

That should let the Project tool find a transformation and hopefully, the data will then line up.

Comment: I used your recommended 4312 geoCRS and it worked out smoothly.Thank you for the helpful advice!

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know. If you can, can you click the checkmark on the answer? That lets other people know that the answer worked.